# How to configure the intermediate output directory in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to organize my workspace and want my intermediate objects to be put in the `..\build\obj` folder in relation to my .csproj file. So I put:

`<IntermediateOutputPath>..\build\obj\Debug</IntermediateOutputPath>`

in the .csproj file. The intermediate objects are now put in that location when the solution is built, but the problem is that an `obj` directory is still created in the directory the .csproj file is in (something to the effect of `obj\Debug\TempPE`) when the solution is opened. What is this directory for, and how can I relocate it?

Comment: I've just switched over to C# from C++ and have gotten very used to having my workspace constructed a very specific way. I would like to maintain the same workspace structure in C#.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815056/move-intermediates-directory-on-c-projects-in-visual-studio

Comment: The way that certain 'enterprisey' version control systems make it difficult to deal with non-versioned objects inside a versioned folder. Beyond that, I've never cared for having build objects mixed in with my source tree.

Comment: I posted a solution for VS2013 at the [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815056/move-intermediates-directory-on-c-projects-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could try to do this (don't forget that there are Debug and Release sections which will be used depending on what type of build you are targeting):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>..\build\obj</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>..\build\obj</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I've tried this. An obj\ directory is still being generated in the same directory as the .csproj file. When I build, the intermediates go to the directory specified by the .csproj file, but for some reason this obj\ directory is still being generated in the .csproj file directory as well.

Comment: @blachniet - Visual Studio creates that obj directory. Its annoying, but if you don't use VS and just use MSBuild from the command line, it works fine. I have no idea why Microsoft thinks we want to put build output into our source tree.

Answer (score 11):

Do this like Microsoft:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IntermediateOutputPath Condition=" '$(PlatformName)' == 'AnyCPU' ">$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath Condition=" '$(PlatformName)' != 'AnyCPU' ">$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)$(PlatformName)\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, all these years later, I attempted these conditional statements and they seem to be ignored.  It just applies the last one in the list, regardless of the condition.  Note I did that in the Directory.Build.Props file at the solution level.

Answer (score 5):

According to this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets), a file named `Directory.Build.props` can be created in the folder that containes the `.csproj` project file. In order to relocate the `obj` folder, we can add

```
<BaseOutputPath>..\Build</BaseOutputPath>
```

to the `PropertyGroup` section in `.csproj` project file, and write

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>..\Intermediate\obj</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
        <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)\$(Configuration)</IntermediateOutputPath>
        <!--The following is the default configuration for "MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath"-->
        <!--<MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)</MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath>-->
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

to the `Directory.Build.props` file.

Comment: Thanks you! This should actually be the top answer because it's the only way to get rid of annoying `obj` directory VS creates in the project dir.
The `BaseOutputPath` can also be set in `Directory.Build.props` (just to keep everything in one place). In this case, specifying paths relative to the solution or project dir will be preferable, e.g.`<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)Obj\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>`.

Answer (score 3):

I've used:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>$(OBJDIR)\$(SolutionName)\bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(OBJDIR)\$(SolutionName)\obj\$(Configuration)\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

(In Visual Studio 2012 Beta, FWIW), and it works fine.

The OBJDIR on my machine points to `E:\BuildOutput`.

Comment: I believe the whole purpose of the `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` is to *not* include `$(Configuration)` at that point (i.e., it's name, "base...").  You're supposed to use `IntermediateOutputPath` to tack that part on. Also, note that as you have it, you create a repetition of two backslashes at the end of your `IntermediateOutputPath`.