# dotnet Release build vs dotnet publish

Tags: .net

What is the difference between

```
dotnet publish MyApi.csproj -o output
```

and

```
dotnet build MyApi.csproj -c release -o output
```

Trying to find the most "ideal" command to use in my yaml pipeline for .zip artifact deploy. Which one should I use?

Comment: I believe they're the same thing, but wait for more input.  Personally, I'd do publish.

Comment: I would use `dotnet publish`, which also takes `-c` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `dotnet publish` to get a "clean" folder with the files that need to be published.

When you use `dotnet build`, the `bin\Release` folder may contain additional files that do not need to be published, such as the intermediate build files. While there are [solutions to keep the intermediate files out of the way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3311212/335858), using `dotnet publish` lets you avoid this issue altogether.

Note: `dotnet publish` also takes the `-c` flag, which lets you specify the configuration the way you did with your `dotnet build` command.